# action is updating state, but props from mapStateToProps showing as undefined in Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm writing a simple multiple-choice assessment app that lets you click on an answer, where it is then highlighted and added to the answers array. Other choices are taken out of the answers array if a user has already clicked them. The action is dispatched correctly, but the props I use in the component show up as undefined. I'm sure I've over complicated this (I'm quite a beginner) so any help is appreciated. I've looked at about 7 other SO posts, but the setup is different and they don't include multiple items in mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps (not sure if this makes a difference.)

question.reducer.js

```
const INITIAL_STATE=
{
  answers:[],
  i:1,
  j:2,
  k:3,
  l:4,
  i_Checked:"",
  j_Checked:"",
  k_Checked:"",
  l_Checked:""
};
const questionReducer=(state=INITIAL_STATE,action)=>{
  switch(action.type){
case QuestionActionTypes.CLICK_I:
return{
  ...state,
  answers: changeI(state.i,state.j,state.k,state.l,state.answers),
  i_Checked:"checked",
  j_Checked:"",
  k_Checked:"",
  l_Checked:""
};
```

"changeI" in the reducer is a util function from my utils.js folder that gives the proper div a className of "checked" and adds it to the answers array if it's not included while taking out the other multiple choice options out of the answers array. That all works just fine. It's the props from mapStateToProps that are driving me crazy!

component in question

```
import React from 'react';
import './multiple-choice.styles.scss';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {i_Clicked,j_Clicked,k_Clicked,l_Clicked} from '../../redux/question/question.actions';

const MultipleChoice= ({i_Checked,j_Checked, k_Checked, l_Checked, i_Clicked,j_Clicked,k_Clicked,l_Clicked,i,j,k,l})=>{

    let answerUrl="../../../public/images/answer";
  let formVisible="none";
  let mcVisible="";


  return(

  <div  style={{display: mcVisible}}>
        <div className='row'>
        //answer choice 1
        <div onClick={i_Clicked} className={`${i_Checked} column`} >
          <img alt="Possible Answer" src={`${answerUrl}${i}.png`}/>
         </div>

//answer choice 2
        <div onClick={j_Clicked} className={`${j_Checked} column`}>
          <img alt="Possible Answer" src={`${answerUrl}${j}.png`}/>
         </div>
        </div>

    <div className="row">
    //answer choice 3
    <div onClick={k_Clicked} className={`${k_Checked} column`}>
      <img alt="Possible Answer" src={`${answerUrl}${k}.png`}/>
    </div>

//asnwer choice 4
    <div  onClick={l_Clicked} className={`${l_Checked} column`}>
      <img alt="Possible Answer" src={`${answerUrl}${l}.png`}/>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

  )
}
const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch=>({
    i_Clicked: ()=> dispatch(i_Clicked()),
    j_Clicked: ()=> dispatch(j_Clicked()),
    k_Clicked: ()=> dispatch(k_Clicked()),
    l_Clicked: ()=> dispatch(l_Clicked())

});

const mapStateToProps=state=>({

    i_Checked: state.i_Checked,
    j_Checked:state.j_Checked,
    k_Checked:state.k_Checked,
    l_Checked:state.l_Checked,
    i:state.i,
    j:state.j,
    k:state.k,
    l:state.l
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(MultipleChoice);
```

When I click on the first answer choice of the problem (represented by the letter "i" for i,j,k,l) it shows up in the answer array and i_checked has the value of "checked" so the action seems to work, it's just the props aren't loading in the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you post your root reducer file?. the place that you use `combineReducers`

```
export default combineReducers({
  question: QuestionReducer,
});
```

If this is how you have implemented your `mapStateToProps` should be changed as follows

```
const mapStateToProps=state=>({
    i_Checked: state.question.i_Checked,
    j_Checked:state.question.j_Checked,
    k_Checked:state.question.k_Checked,
    l_Checked:state.question.l_Checked,
    i:state.question.i,
    j:state.question.j,
    k:state.question.k,
    l:state.question.l
});
```

state will consist of the whole redux store and `question` fill refer data related to the question section